# Compute the sum of values in one column, if row in another column contains item in list

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe, numpy

In python I have a dataframe that looks like:

```
Column1               Column2
[a,b,c,d]             4    
[a,f,g]               3
[b,c]                 6
[a,c,d]               5
```

I would like to compute a third column, that adds the value in Column2 for each time one of the items is present in Column1 (for example in the first row it would be a=4+3+5, b=4+6, c=5+6+5, d=4+5, so in total 4+3+5+4+6+5+6+5+4+5=47):

```
Column1               Column2     Column3
[a,b,c,d]             4           47
[a,f,g]               3           21
[b,c]                 6           26
[a,c,d]               5           37
```

I've tried my best with query and indexing but with no success, thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with `explode`, then create the mapping dict and `groupby` back

```
s = df.explode('Column1')
d = s.groupby('Column1')['Column2'].sum()
s['new'] = s['Column1'].map(d)
out = s.groupby(level=0).agg({'Column1':list,'Column2':'first','new':'sum'})
out
        Column1  Column2  new
0  [a, b, c, d]        4   46
1     [a, f, g]        3   18
2        [b, c]        6   25
3     [a, c, d]        5   36
```

Notice :

c = 4+6+5

Answer (score 0):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Column1': [['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], ['a', 'f', 'g'], ['b', 'c'], ['a', 'c', 'd']],
                   'Column2': [4, 3, 6, 5]})
df1 = df.explode('Column1')
df['Column3'] = df1.groupby(level=0).apply(
    lambda d: d.Column1.apply(lambda x: df1.loc[df1.Column1 == x, 'Column2'].sum()).sum())
print(df)
```

```
        Column1  Column2  Column3
0  [a, b, c, d]        4       46
1     [a, f, g]        3       18
2        [b, c]        6       25
3     [a, c, d]        5       36
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's start from the easier to comprehend version, step by step.

1. Explode *Column1*:

   ```
   wrk = df.explode(column='Column1')
   ```

   The result is:

   ```
     Column1  Column2
   0       a        4
   0       b        4
   0       c        4
   0       d        4
   1       a        3
   1       f        3
   1       g        3
   2       b        6
   2       c        6
   3       a        5
   3       c        5
   3       d        5
   ```
2. Compute weights for each element from lists in *Column1*:

   ```
   weight = wrk.groupby('Column1').sum().rename(columns={'Column2': 'Weight'})
   ```

   The result is:

   ```
            Weight
   Column1        
   a            12
   b            10
   c            15
   d             9
   f             3
   g             3
   ```

   Note some differences to your counting, e.g. weight for *c*
   is *4 + 6 + 5* = *15*.
3. Join *Column1* from *wrk* with *weight*:

   ```
    wrk2 = wrk[['Column1']].join(weight, on='Column1')
   ```

   The result is:

   ```
     Column1  Weight
   0       a      12
   0       b      10
   0       c      15
   0       d       9
   1       a      12
   1       f       3
   1       g       3
   2       b      10
   2       c      15
   3       a      12
   3       c      15
   3       d       9
   ```
4. And the final step is to compute the new column:

   ```
   df['Column3'] = wrk2.groupby(level=0).Weight.sum()
   ```

   The result is:

   ```
           Column1  Column2  Column3
   0  [a, b, c, d]        4       46
   1     [a, f, g]        3       18
   2        [b, c]        6       25
   3     [a, c, d]        5       36
   ```

But if you want more concise code, you can "compress" the above
solution to:

```
wrk = df.explode(column='Column1')
df['Column3'] = wrk[['Column1']].join(wrk.groupby('Column1').sum().rename(
    columns={'Column2': 'Weight'}), on='Column1').groupby(level=0).Weight.sum()
```